# Laravel 7 Sanctum logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel 7 with Sanctum authentication for my app.
How can i implement the logout procedure?
I use:

```
Auth::user()->tokens()->delete();
```

and it works, but It delete all tokens of this user.
i would like to delete only the token of the user who requested the logout, in this way the other sessions should remain open

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to specify the user  :

```
// Revoke a specific user token
Auth::user()->tokens()->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

```
// Get user who requested the logout
$user = request()->user(); //or Auth::user()

// Revoke current user token
$user->tokens()->where('id', $user->currentAccessToken()->id)->delete();
```

Update of **[Laravel 7, 8, 9, 10](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#revoking-tokens)** :

```
// Revoke the token that was used to authenticate the current request...
$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();

// Revoke a specific token...
$user->tokens()->where('id', $tokenId)->delete();
```

Comment: How can I get the token ID?

Comment: @enfix it would be `Auth::user()->tokens()->where('id', $id)->get('field_name')->first();` the `field_name` is your `column` name where you store token.

Comment: No, I don't know how to set $id variable. is not the id token?

Comment: @enfix, in this case id and token are not same. If you are logged in user then you can get $id by `$id = Auth::user()->id;` So it would be `Auth::user()->tokens()->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->delete();`

Comment: It don't work: Auth::user()->id is the user ID, not token ID.

Comment: @enfix, I give you `user ID` not token id

Comment: It' does't work (no error, but nothing appends).I need to identify the specific token to rewoke/delete and not all token about the specific user.

Comment: I solve use this solution: Auth::user()->tokens()->where('id', Auth::user()->currentAccessToken()->id)->delete();

Comment: Call to undefined method App\User::tokens()

Comment: @Rejaul `App\Models\User::tokens() `

Answer (score 13):

For the logout, you can directly delete the token if you use currentAccessToken().

```php
$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
```

Comment: Call to undefined method App\User::currentAccessToken()

Comment: add `HasApiTokens` trait on your `User` model

Comment: No dice even with the trait on my request user :/

Comment: this also work **auth()->user()->tokens()->delete()** if you use current AccessToken

Answer (score 12):

**To Logout, In laravel 9 & 10**

```
   use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;


   // Get bearer token from the request
    $accessToken = $request->bearerToken();
    
    // Get access token from database
    $token = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($accessToken);

    // Revoke token
    $token->delete();
```

Answer (score 3):

for people who got error regarding `currentAccessToken()` that null or undefined, don't forget to put your logout route inside `auth:sanctum` middleware.

so after using

```
$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
```

put the logout route like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group( function () {
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'signout']);
});
```

Comment: And don't forget to add the Bearer token to your request

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of your tokens are for authentication:

```
$user = \auth('sanctum')->user();
foreach ($user->tokens as $token) {
    $token->delete();
}
```