# Correct way of doing Sanctum logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

When logging out, do we need to call one or both of the following?

1. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218096/1137199):

   ```
   request()->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
   ```
2. As suggested [here](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/87#issuecomment-595952005)

   ```
   Auth::guard('web')->logout();
   ```

Comment: In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum) it mentions two ways to authenticate. One is with tokens and the other is "SPA authentication" which uses Laravel's built-in authentication. If you're using the first way you need to delete the token but if you're using the second one you need to logout via the web guard

Comment: @apokryfos: Doesn't appear to be the case. I'm using SPA authentication method. But unless I call `currentAccessToken()->delete()`, I can still access protected routes. I'm checking through Postman just to make sure nothing else is interfering.

Comment: @apokryfos: Just found that I only need to call `currentAccessToken()->delete()` for successful logout. The other call is completely unnecessary. This is still a cookie-based authentication where we need to call `sanctum/csrf-cookie` before login to get our XSRF-Token.

Comment: To clarify using the spa method implies using the web guard when doing `auth()->attempt` the csrf token does indicate that there's a session involved in the process