# How to Logout All Devices Without Password in Laravel Sanctum?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, logout, laravel-session, sanctum

I am using Laravel Sanctum for both API and SPA authentication.

When an SPA user logs out, I need to logout him from all other devices too without asking for password. This is a requirement (and hence I cannot go other-way).

I am deleting all tokens of the target user during logout. And clearing user session does not delete/expire sessions from other devices. I need to delete all sessions of that particular user (from all devices).

I cannot find a way to obtain this.

Comment: `Auth::user()->tokens()->where('id', $id)->delete();` $id is your user id https://stackoverflow.com/a/62497133/4575350

Comment: @sta It does not logout from other devices using Laravel Session.

Comment: If you are using session based authentication, then  deleting all tokens will not delete the session. Currently there are no way to delete a user session without logout